# Should I do-release-upgrade?

Tags: do-release-upgrade

I have an oldish net book running 12.04.5 LTS.  It works well enough, and I am happy with it.

However, 14.02.2 LTS is out (for a while now), as I am reminded often by the suggestion to `do-release-updgrade`. Should I do it?  My concerns are loss of data and that the upgrade might be more stressful for my little Intel atom powered net book.

My specifications are:

- 1G Ram
- 32 bit
- Intel Atom 2 x 1.66GHz
- Intel built in graphics

Comment: how much RAM? 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: I think there is no need to upgrade, if everything works. Support of your system is till '17. Upgrade may go not very smooth.

Comment: 1GB isn't enough ram, you need at least 2 and I like to have 4 on my virtual machines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it ain't broke, don't fix it.

Upgrading might cause more problems than it'll solve.